# Free WAV to MP4 converters for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, video, audio, video-editing

I would like to take a WAV sound file and convert it to an MP4 video file, perhaps attaching a static picture to the MP4 video file. I want to so this because I want to post a WAV on a social network which does not accept sound files but accepts video files.

Where can I find free software for the PC (Windows 7) to accomplish this task?

Comment: I can't seem to find one which is (A) free, and (2) can be installed on a PC as opposed to being online.

Comment: I've been using [Any Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/) (Free; not paid one) for years. See if it helps you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Virtualdub.

1. File>Open video file (choose Image sequence file type, then choose your img)
2. Audio>Audio from other file (choose your wav or mp3)
3. Video>Frame Rate (check the option "Change so video and audio durations match")
   [image]
4. File>Save as Avi

Here is a link to directly export in mp4 from virtualdub:
https://encodingtalk.com/threads/virtualdub-save-direct-to-mp4-fraps-to-youtube-with-external-encoders.2446/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please explain how to carry out step 3 in some more detail? I would like to know how to make the video and audio durations match, not sure about how to go about doing this.

Comment: "Change so video and audio durations match" is a checkbox you have to check. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using a CLI, you can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), OS X, Linux
- Allows to convert [from wav to mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5887311/395857)
- Is CLI so you can batch.